# How to remove the inner HTML of my H1 Page title tag?

Tags: magento2, phtml, seo

For SEO purpose, I would like to remove the `span` tag of my pages Catalog and Product View. You can see the default render below:

[image: Magento 2 page title h1 with inner span]

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to override it using your custom theme, copy the native file from:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml
```

to:

```
app/design/frontend/MyCompany/MyCustomTheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/title.phtml
```

You can use this content:

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading());
?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
<div class="page-title-wrapper<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $cssClass ?>">
    <h1 class="page-title"
        <?php if ($block->getId()): ?> id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getId() ?>" <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()): ?>
            aria-labelledby="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getAddBaseAttributeAria() ?>"
        <?php endif; ?>>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```